# iOS/Android application with server API's to pass information

Tags: php, android, iphone, mysql, ios

I'm  working on project for iOS/ Android application that allow user to Register/Login and than create/share and store files to the server and share it with other users.

To meet this purpose i been following this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app but i found its very basic and i need more information before i start working on it.

My question is, how to create an application for example like Path: https://path.com or instagram, that allow apps to sync with server using API's and pass data between server, phone and users without offering Website to users?

Is there any  pre-built open source php/mysql API's that we can use for this purpose?

Any brief tutorial that explain steps to do this (since until now i use to work on basic iOS app and need not require any interaction to server and stuff)?

In project im using php/mysql, in my research i found people also advice to use AFnetworking (http://afnetworking.com/) to replace stranded url fetching, any opinion on that?

I'm hoping to have great discussion on this question since there is lot of questions out there on this topic but non have full descriptive answers!

Answer (score 0):

you can create our own server using tomcat and get the path that act as url for you..and there are many third party framework available for parsing or in iphone they have there own using NSJSONSerialization.you can read the detail from this link.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thanks for that! do you know any open source apis for php that can be use in app

Comment: i am not so much familiar about open source apis but see this link it might help https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API  and if you are satisfied with my answer accept it.